# Problem deploy springboot like service in ec2

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I run application by: `java -jar app.jar`. Its working good!

But setup run like service by https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html.

When `sudo service ccth start`, then following error occurs:

```
/etc/init.d/ccth: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 2:Dr�Lorg/PK: No such file or directory

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 3:Dr�Lorg/springframework/PK: No such file or directory

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 4:Dr�Lorg/springframework/boot/PK: No such file or directory

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 5: $'\bDr\376L': command not found

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 6:Dr�L%org/springframework/boot/loader/data/PK: No such file or directory

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 7:Dr�L/springframework/boot/loader/jar/PK: No such file or directory

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `$'org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/PK\003\004''

/etc/init.d/ccth: line 8: Dr�L(org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/PK'
```

How i can fix them?

Comment: Does it work when you execute `./app.jar start`? It could be that you are trying to start a simple jar and not an executable jar (as in `<executable>true</executable>`).

Comment: Yeah!! Thank you so much. I fixed it, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely missing the `<executable>` option in your build configuration. Without it you are producing a regular JAR, not executable one.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <executable>true</executable>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for posting the question.  I have spent some time researching exactly the same issue.  I use gradle to build jar and I needed to include:

```
bootJar {
    launchScript()
}
```

Then just make sure that you run newly created file.